# python itertools.product giving result wrongly as [(['x'],), ([0, 1],), ([0, 1, 2],)]

Tags: python, python-itertools

I have a list

```
e = [['x'], [0, 1], [0, 1, 2]]
```

From this list, I would like to produce below output.

```
[('x', 0, 0), ('x', 0, 1), ('x', 1, 0), ('x', 1, 1), ('x', 2, 0), ('x', 2,1)]
```

Below is the code I used

```
import itertools
f=[[0], [2], [3]]
e=[['x']if f[j][0]==0 else range(f[j][0]) for j in range(len(f))]
print(e)
List1_=[]
for i in itertools.product(e):
  List1_.append(i)
print(List1_)
```

but I am getting output as

```
[(['x'],), ([0, 1],), ([0, 1, 2],)]
```

thanks,
Sans

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's what that [`itertools.product`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.product) is for. But you need to change the second and 3rd item in order to create the expected product.

Also note that you need to use `*` operand for unpacking your nested list. Because `product` accepts multiple iterable and calculates the product of them. Thus you need to pass your sub lists instead of the whole of your list.

```
>>> e = [['x'], [0, 1, 2], [0, 1]]   
>>> list(product(*e))
[('x', 0, 0), ('x', 0, 1), ('x', 1, 0), ('x', 1, 1), ('x', 2, 0), ('x', 2, 1)]
```

Answer (score 0):

You were not unpacking `e` in your code:

```
>>> list(product(e))
[(['x'],), ([0, 1],), ([0, 1, 2],)]
>>> 
>>> list(product(*e))
[('x', 0, 0), ('x', 0, 1), ('x', 0, 2), ('x', 1, 0), ('x', 1, 1), ('x', 1, 2)]
>>>
```

Quoting from [Python Docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html?highlight=groupby#itertools.product):

> `itertools.product(*iterables, repeat=1)` Cartesian product of input
>   iterables.
>
> Equivalent to nested for-loops in a generator expression. For example,
>   product(A, B) returns the same as ((x,y) for x in A for y in B).

If order matters to you than, just re-order your `e` list as :

```
>>> e = [['x'], [0, 1, 2], [0, 1]]
```

Then you can get your expected output:

```
>>> list(product(*e))
[('x', 0, 0), ('x', 0, 1), ('x', 1, 0), ('x', 1, 1), ('x', 2, 0), ('x', 2, 1)]
```